# Getting a cartesian product

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my question. I'm on postgres and I have the next [conceptual schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdWr6.jpg)

My objective is to show game's code, name's team and  name's players who has played that game. I've only got to show game's code and name's team with:

```
select g.code,home_team,t1.name,away_team,t2.name
from pldata.game g,pldata.team t1,pldata.team t2
where t1.code = g.home_team
and t2.code = g.away_team
order by 1
```

I've tryed to do this for get the name's player too

```
select g.code,t.name,p.surname
from pldata.team t,pldata.player p,pldata.player p2,pldata.game g,pldata.team t2
where t.code=p.belongs
and t2.code=p2.belongs
and t.code=g.home_team
and t2.code=g.away_team 
order by code
```

But that makes a cartesian product and I don't know why. Any kind of help is fine, so thanks you.

Comment: Switch to modern, explicit JOIN syntax, and life will become easier!

Comment: change your select list to `select g.code, t.name, p.surname, t2.name AS name2 , p2.surname AS surname2` , and you'll see the light!

Comment: I tried and I continued seeing the cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am at work and can't check the image you linked.It's better to always post a data sample of all your tables when  you ask such a question.

With no data, I can only make guesses.

Your first mistake, is that you use **implicit JOIN** syntax instead of **explicit JOIN** syntax. this makes your query hard to read and thus to debug and understand.

This is your query rewritten in explicit syntax, you should **always** build your SQL like this:

```
SELECT g.code,g.home_team, t1.name, p1.surname, g.away_team, t2.name, p2.surname
FROM pldata.game g
INNER JOIN pldata.team   t1 ON t1.code=g.home_team
INNER JOIN pldata.player p1 ON t1.code=p1.belongs
INNER JOIN pldata.team   t2 ON t2.code=g.away_team 
INNER JOIN pldata.player p2 ON t2.code=p2.belongs
ORDER BY g.code
```

And it should never returns a cartesian product because there's no `CROSS JOIN` in this query.

So the question is, **are the teams multiplayer** ?

If yes, then you will have several rows returned for one game because there will be one row for each player of the 2 teams. This might be what you think to be the cartesian product.

With the explicit join syntax, it is very easy to debug your query to understand where the problem (if any) lies. Just remove the 2 joins on player table and retry.

If it's multiplayer and you want only one row per game but still want all the players in the results, you should do a `GROUP_CONCAT`. The expression is not supported in postgress but you can use a `string_agg(the_column, ',')` which achieve the same thing. But you can only do the concatanation of players for one team:

```
    SELECT g.code, g.home_team, string_agg(p1.surname,',') AS Team1Players
    FROM pldata.game g
    INNER JOIN pldata.team   t1 ON t1.code=g.home_team
    INNER JOIN pldata.player p1 ON t1.code=p1.belongs
    GROUP BY g.code, g.home_team
```

The solution to have both teams on one row is to make a jointure between 2 agreggated `GROUP BY` queries, for each team :

```
SELECT Team1.code,Team1.home_team, Team1.Team1Players, Team2.away_team, Team2.Team2Players  
FROM    
(   
    SELECT g.code, g.home_team, string_agg(p1.surname,',') AS Team1Players
    FROM pldata.game g
    INNER JOIN pldata.team   t1 ON t1.code=g.home_team
    INNER JOIN pldata.player p1 ON t1.code=p1.belongs
    GROUP BY g.code, g.home_team 
) Team1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT g.code, g.away_team, string_agg(p2.surname,',')  AS Team2Players
    FROM pldata.game g
    INNER JOIN pldata.team   t2 ON t2.code=g.away_team 
    INNER JOIN pldata.player p2 ON t2.code=p2.belongs
    GROUP BY g.code, g.away_team 
) Team2
ON  Team1.Code = Team2.code
ORDER BY Team1.code
```

Not sure if all this answers your question, and if I didn't make some syntax mistakes, but the idea is there and t least you have some hints to move further.

If my queries don't work or if you need further assistance, you should absolutely edit your question to add DLL and data so we have a playground.

Comment: Thanks for your advices Thomas. That was so helpfully. This is my second post on stackoverflow and I'm not used how to do it. About Joins, my teacher thinks that don't are the way, so they didn't teaches very well to us. I think that you are working as sql programmer so what do you think about this. Is he wrong?

Comment: If you mean that you teacher tells you that implcit joins should be used instead of explicit joins.... he should really stop teaching. Just make some googling about this and that will give you an idea of how bad he is ;-)